# How to add WCF service on IIS Express?

Tags: wcf, iis-express

I have the wcf service package, waiting to be put in IIS. Everything goes fine when I create a virtual directory on the default website and etc. But when I try to access the path in Chrome I get an error:

```
It is an error to use a section registered as allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level. This error can be caused by a virtual directory not being configured as an application in IIS.
```

When I comment this section:

```
<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"
multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
```

I can access the directory but not the service. Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried a little more and figured out what I was doing wrong. I can't create an virtual path under the Default Website. I had to create my own site, which appoint to the folder where my WCF files are storage. Something like this:

```
appcmd add site /name:WcfService1 /id:2 /physicalPath:C:\WcfService1 /bindings:http/*:8080
```

This way the virtual directory will be marked as an applicattion and everything will work just fine.